# Retrieving data from Firebase Realtime Database in Android - recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve data from Firebase Realtime Database and display this data inside recyclerview but I can't do it and I can't understand why because I tried everything(Google / StackOverflow etc) and nothing works.

The code seems to be ok but when I run the app it gives me these messages: No setter/field for Surname found on class com.example.ipill.Users

I checked how to solve the problem and nothing works, I deleted and create a couple of times the database and nothing.

I'm new to Android Studio and I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Below I will attach the code and the database. The thing that I don't understand is that when I add a new Object to the database with Name = Alex I can see the new recycler view containing a new item inside, that means that the apps understand that there are more objects with Name = Alex but can't I retrieve the of that object from the database.

Thank you in advance.

CODE ACTIVITY

```
package com.example.ipill;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.GenericTypeIndicator;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class FirebaseSearch extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText mSearchField;
private ImageButton mSearchBtn;

private RecyclerView mResultList;



private DatabaseReference mUserDatabase;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_firebasesearch);

    mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

    mSearchField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_field);

    mSearchBtn = findViewById(R.id.search_btn);
    mResultList = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.result_list);

    mResultList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mResultList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    mSearchBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String searchText = mSearchField.getText().toString();

            firebaseUserSearch(searchText);

        }
    });


}

private void firebaseUserSearch(String searchText) {

    Toast.makeText(FirebaseSearch.this, "Started Search", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Query firebaseSearchQuery = mUserDatabase.orderByChild("Name").startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + "\uf8ff");

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UsersViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UsersViewHolder>(

            Users.class,
            R.layout.list_layout,
            UsersViewHolder.class,
            firebaseSearchQuery

    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(UsersViewHolder viewHolder, Users model, int position) {
            viewHolder.setDetails(model.getName(), model.getSurname());

        }
    };

    mResultList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

}


// View Holder Class

public static class UsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View mView;

    public UsersViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;

    }

    public void setDetails(String name, String surname) {

        TextView user_name = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.name_text);
        TextView user_surname = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.status_text);

        user_name.setText(name);
        user_surname.setText(surname);


    }

}

}
```

DATABASE:

[image: This is the image with the database]
[image]
The problem that I have:

```
W/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered             
on the client. Consider adding '".indexOn": "Name"' at Users to your security and Firebase Database     
rules for better performance
W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for Surname found on class com.example.ipill.Users (fields/setters are 
case sensitive!)
W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for Name found on class com.example.ipill.Users (fields/setters are 
case sensitive!)
W/m.example.ipil: Accessing hidden field Landroid/view/View;- 
>mAccessibilityDelegate:Landroid/view/View$AccessibilityDelegate; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
```

**Model CLASS**

```
package com.example.ipill;

public class Users {

public String name, surname;


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}


public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}


public Users(String name, String surname, String status) {
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;

}

public Users(){

}

}
```

Comment: There are multiple error message in the output, each of which has been covered in multiple questions before. Did you search for those already? What did you learn from the answers to those questions about what might cause the problem in the code you shared?

Comment: Using an unspecified index error -> I tried to fix it by adding .indexOf : Name to the rules of the DATABASE and it doesn't change anything I get the same error.             No setter/field for Surname found on class error -> I find a fix on StackOverflow but it doesn't work for what I want to do. So I don't have other things to try so I asked for help because I tried almost an entire day to solve the problems.

Comment: If you still get the same error, you didn't define the index correctly. Without seeing your minimal rules with which to reproduce the problem, there's not much more we can say. Also note that each of these errors is a separate problem. Including multiple problems in a single question makes it harder to help and thus less likely that someone will help.

Comment: I added the rules of my database, I followed the documentation from the website when I added the index, hope I didn't miss something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is quite explicit on what you need to do:

> Consider adding '".indexOn": "Name"' at Users

So you need to add `".indexOn": "Name"` at the `Users` node in your rules.

So:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Users": {
      ".indexOn": "Name"
    }
  }
}
```

The square brackets are fine `["Name"]`, but right now  you're defining the index on the wrong level.

Comment: Thank you so much, I missed this part "Users". Now I don't have that error anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You need  create model class and inside getter setter

Comment: Already did that, you can check it if you want I just update the post with the code of the model class. Thank you in advance